# Python RandomForest converting rfe.support_ to list

Tags: python, arrays, random-forest

After running an RFE model with RandomForests I get a rfe.support_ result (array with True and False).

If I do df.columns[rfe.support_] I get a list of retained values. How can I get this values as a list? x.columns[rfe.support_] seems to be a non callable object.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
rfe = RFE(estimator=clf_rf_3, n_features_to_select=2, step=1)
rfe = rfe.fit(iris["data"], iris["target"])
rfe.support_
```

rfe.support_ is an array with false and true what I want is to get a list of the retained variables which correspond to the 'true' in the rfe.support_ array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use to '.tolist()' function as -
list = rfe.support_.tolist()

Now you have a list of the array items

then use the for loop to filter out the true values from the entire list created all the while maintaining a separate list as the index of the true values.

list2 = []

for i in range(1, len(list)):     # iterating over the list

```
if(int(list[i])==1):          # for the true values

    list2.append(i)           # the separate list with the index of true value items
```